# Make command with multiple optional arguments

Tags: macros

I wish to make a command `\DDF` that prints `$\delta\Delta\Phi$` with optional scripts. Could you please help me do this?

Here are desired inputs to give desired outputs:

1. `\DDF` should give `$\delta\Delta\Phi$`
2. `\DDF{a}{b}` should give `$\delta\Delta\Phi_a^b$`
3. `\DDF{a}{}` should give `$\delta\Delta\Phi_a$`
4. `\DDF{a}` should give `$\delta\Delta\Phi_a$`
5. `\DDF{}{b}` should give `$\delta\Delta\Phi^b$`

I think the following may (almost) work -- except for (4) -- but even so I'm not sure it's the rigorous or elegant way to do it:

```
\newcommand{\DDF}[2]{\delta\Delta\Phi_{#1}^{#2}}
```

Comment: Why don't you just define `\newcommand{\DDF}{\delta\Delta\Phi}` then use `\DDF` or `\DDF_a` or `\DDF^b`?

Comment: If `\DDF` - defined as intended by you - is used with mathmode, e.g., `$a^2+\DDF{a}{b}+b^2$`, then you get `$a^2+$\delta\Delta\Phi_a^b$+b^2$` which is a problem as `\delta\Delta\Phi_a^b` is not in math-mode. If you do `$a^2+$\DDF{a}{b}$+b^2$`, then you get three separate adjacent formulas which probably is not what you want. Thus I suggest not to wrap entire definition-texts into `$`.

Comment: What about things like `\DDF{a}{\empty}` or `\DDF{\@gobbletwo{x}{y}}{b}` ?

Comment: as Phelype says, the standard `^` and `_` syntax is preferable here, it makes it far more natural to have both optional, as your case 5 shows, you can't omit the first argument if you want to use the second.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not difficult (but with brackets, not braces):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\DDF}{oo}{%
  \delta\Delta\Phi
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
    \IfValueT{#1}{_{#1}}
  }{%
   _{#1}^{#2}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$\DDF$

$\DDF[a][b]$

$\DDF[a][]$

$\DDF[a]$

$\DDF[][b]$

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, it's not clear what the advantage is over

```
\newcommand{\DDF}{\delta\Delta\Phi}
```

and input as

```
$\DDF$

$\DDF_{a}^{b}$

$\DDF_{a}$

$\DDF_{a}$

$\DDF^{b}$
```

The coding you propose is much less clear, in my opinion, and you *must* remember that the subscript comes first, whereas you can do

```
\DDF^{b}_{a}
```

and get identical result to `\DDF_{a}^{b}`.